# Can inheritance be modelled in app engine datastore by same kind and different properties?

Tags: google-app-engine, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Consider the following models and their properties:

```
Media
  ├── Image
  │       - CreatedAt
  │       - Width
  │       - Height
  ├── Audio
  │       - CreatedAt
  │       - Duration
  └── Video
          - CreatedAt
          - Width
          - Height
          - Duration
```

There are a few ways of implementing this:

### 1. Different kinds, different properties

This can be done by [PolyModel in ndb](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass). We have a base model `Media` which factors the common properties, and `Image`, `Audio` and `Video` can be subclasses.

Since each subclass has its own kind, querying the N newest media is not possible without in-memory sorting.

### 2. Same kind, same properties

Implementing this in datastore using [single table inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) is possible, but there is no point in enforcing 'unused' properties in a schemaless database. For example, there will be many rows for `Audio` entities with unused `Width` and `Height` properties.

Querying the N newest media is possible here, but it has the disadvantage of unused properties.

### 3. Same kind, different properties

Unlike relational databases, datastore does not require entities of the same kind to have the same properties. It is possible that `Image`, `Audio` and `Video` all to have the same `Media` kind, while having their own set of properties. An extra property called `Type` is necessary to distinguish them from each other.

Querying the N newest media is possible with this method, and there is no unused properties. But are there any gotchas with this approach? Are we losing any application level schema safety and data integrity with this?

Comment: [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify) (for Java) supports polymorphism using your 3rd approach.  The (old) [docs](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Polymorphism) describe some of the limitations but I've not (yet!) run into any problems.  Because the classes use the same kind, you need to be careful with your key IDs/names as an `Image` and `Audio` with the same ID/name would have the same key.

Comment: I am not sure why you say option 1 doesn't support querying N newest media.  You would just query Media model and not the individual subclasses and you will get all types.

Comment: in option 1 `Media` is like an abstract class, there is no `Media` kind entity in the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what ndb's polymodel was designed for. However, it works differently than you described. Consider the following definitions:

```
class Media(polymodel.PolyModel):
  created_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
  ...

class Image(Media):
  height = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  width = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Audio(Media):
  duration = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

Inside Datastore, an `Image` would be stored with the kind `Media` and with a property named `class` equal to `["Media", "Image"]`.

Using the models, you can query for any `Media` using:

```
Media.query()
```

But you can also query for individual types:

```
Image.query()
```

Note that the above query gets converted by ndb into the query:

```
Media.query().filter(Media.class == "Image")
```

Comment: The `class` property is similar to the `Type` property I describe in method 3. Why is that only `"Image"` is not enough? The information this entity is inherited from `Media` is already stored in the kind.

Comment: ndb stores the entire type hierarchy so that if you were to query for a sub-type (i.e. if you had multiple types of images) it would still work.

Comment: Also it's similar to method 3, but by using polymodel you do maintain the "schema" safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an [Expando class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass) with dynamic properties, or just put all the attributes into a [JsonProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties).